# Passing derived class object to function which expects a base class object

Tags: typescript

I came from C++ world to TypeScript based project. And I can't understand how to implement typical C++ code behavior - passing child class object to a function which expects a base class object.

After some googling I wrote the next code:

```
export interface MyInterface {
    myFlag: boolean;
}

class MyInterfaceImpl  implements MyInterface {
  private _myFlag: boolean;

constructor(){...}

get myFlag() {
        return this._myFlag;
    }
set myFlag(value: boolean) {
        this._myFlag = value;
        
        onMyCallbackFunc(this);
    }
}

export function onMyCallbackFunc(myBaseObject : MyInterface) {
    console.log(`${JSON.stringify(myBaseObject)}`);
}
```

But the problem here is that console prints me `{"_myFlag": true}` **instead of** `{"myFlag": true}`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you try to remove `private _myFlag: boolean;` and use `this.myFlag` in the get and set functions?

Comment: Yes, but in this case I must redeclare myFlag in derived class, I can't mark it as private and get\set methods must be renamed(to MyFlag, for instance) because other wise it won't compile. And that solution looks strange as I can set flag as myFlag (without callback) and as MyFlag(with callback) - it's easy to make a mistake